# Printing Sum of Elements Next to Pie Chart in Python

Tags: python, charts, module, pie-chart

I am trying to make a pie chart of school. How can I print the sum of people next to the pie chart?

My code is here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Count_of_people = [66,100,637,160,14718]
Who=["Servant", "Officer", "Teacher","Assistant","Student"]


plt.axis("equal")
plt.pie(Count_of_people,labels=Who, shadow=True, autopct='%1.1f%%',radius=1.5,explode=[0.01,0,0,0.001,0.01])
Sum = sum(Count_of_people)
print(Sum)
plt.show()
```

I have tried to `print(Sum)` but it only helps to print it to console. How can I print it next to the chart?

It should be like this: `Sum of people in School= 15168`

Comment: Did you take a look at `plt.text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
plt.text(-1, -0.5, f"Sum of people in School = {Sum}")
```

where both x & y allow you to manipulate the string position

or even simpler:

```
plt.title(f"Sum of people in School = {Sum}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I take an error when I apply the first solving: "Positional argument after keyword argument" When I applied the second, there was no an error but nothing has changed on figure.

Comment: @Mehmet Akif Çelebi, please have a look at the edited answer. Keyword arguments have to be after the positional arguments or you can drop its names like I did.